# Как сделать каталог проектов домов на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В общем суть такая, необходимо сделать каталог проектов домов, с подробным списком необходимого кол-ва материалов для постройки и с указанием их стоимости в зависимости от города пользователя. Плюс у каждого материала(из списка проекта) должен быть адрес строительного магазина где он может приобрести тот или иной товар.
Т.е. функционал должен быть таким:

Frontend:

1. Пользователь заходит на сайт, по его ip определяется город и его перекидывает на соответствующий поддомен.
2. Выбирает из общего(для всех городов одинаковый) каталога проектов.
3. Нажимает "Получить проект"
4. Получает смету(список материалов) с самой выгодной ценой на каждый материал в его городе.

Backend:

1. Добавление базы магазинов(несколько в одном городе) с общим списком товаров
2. Возможность собрать проект дома из списка товаров.
3. Сформировать смету проекта.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать? Возможно есть какие-то готовые плагины, которые хоть частично реализуют функционал?
Пока что думаю сделать с плагином Woocommerce, но не знаю как реализовать общий каталог товаров для разных магазинов. Так же думаю использовать WT GeoTargeting, для определения города.
Будет полезен любой совет)

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce

1. Оформить дом как вариативный товар - с атрибутом город. В зависимости от выбранного атрибута (город) формировать цену на дом.
2. Все поддомены пустить в директорию сайта, в wp-config.php переопределять домен сайта по домену

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) && ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) )
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = str_replace( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
        
$url_protocol = 'http://';       
        
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
            $url_protocol = 'https://';
        }

        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
            $url_protocol = 'https://';
        }
} elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        $url_protocol = 'https://';
}        
         
$url = $url_protocol .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

define('WP_HOME',$url);

define('WP_SITEURL',$url);
```

3. Сформировать таблицу соответствий поддомен - город. В зависимости от выбранного поддомена для пользователя показывать активный нужный атрибут (город) в товаре с нужной ценой.
4. Фильтрами формировать по активному поддомену нужные мета, чтоб не сломать SEO.

Comment: Решение первых 3-х пунктов из ответа нашел в платной версии плагина WT GeoTargeting. Правда плагин может только заменить цену для выбранного города, но при этом, еще необходимо взять минимальную цену из базы магазинов этого города. 
Думаю сделать мультисайт. Определение города пользователя и переадресацию сделать с помощью этого плагина. Добавить отдельный тип записи "Магазины", в котором они будут добавляться, но вот можно ли сделать для каждого магазина свой список товаров с ценами, взяв его из общего списка товаров Woocommerce?